# Некорректный вывод значения переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вместо имени и фамилии после приветствия выводится не сама переменная, а какая-то другая информация. Что вызвало это, правильно ли я использовал функцию `capitalize`? Вывод на скриншоте:

```
print("Добро пожаловать на страницу регистариции!")
firstname = str(input("Имя: "))
secondname = str(input("Фамилия: "))
print("Спасибо! Добро пожаловать,", firstname.capitalize, secondname.capitalize + "!")
input()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bby8t.png

Comment: Разместите текст ошибки текстом, а не скриншотом, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

Для вызова метода `capitalize` нужно добавить скобки:

```
print("Спасибо! Добро пожаловать,", firstname.capitalize(), secondname.capitalize() + "!")
```

Если вызвать метод без скобок, то Вы обратитесь непосредственно к объекту, в котором хранится метод, а не к самому методу.